# How to get list of child files/directories having parent DataLakeDirectoryClient class instance

Tags: java, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have to scan whole data lake file system. Having code like:

```
PagedIterable<PathItem> pItems = ((DataLakeFileSystemClient)prmParent).listPaths();
for( PathItem pItem : pItems ){
  if pItem.isDirectory() ){
    ((DataLakeFileSystemClient)prmParent).getDirectoryClient(pItem.getName());
  } else {
    ((DataLakeFileSystemClient)prmParent).getFileClient(pItem.getName());
  }
}
```

I get top level dirs/files. But to drill down there must be method listChild() in DataLakeDirectoryClient class.
But i did not find anything similar.
Does anybody know what is the proper way to walk thru the tree?

Thanks. Sergiy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list all path in Azure data lake gen2 file system, please refer to the following code

```
 StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
        String endpoint = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.dfs.core.windows.net", accountName);
        DataLakeServiceClient storageClient = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .credential(credential)
                .buildClient();

        DataLakeFileSystemClient dataLakeFileSystemClient = storageClient.getFileSystemClient("test");
        ListPathsOptions options = new ListPathsOptions();
        options.setRecursive(true);
        PagedIterable<PathItem> pItems = dataLakeFileSystemClient.listPaths(options,null);

        for( PathItem pItem : pItems ){
            if(pItem.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("The directory: " +pItem.getName());
            }else{
                System.out.println("The file : " +pItem.getName());
            }
        }
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.listpathsoptions?view=azure-java-stable)